# How to fix the wrong positioning of the 3D cursor.?

Tags: 3d-cursor

I got this problem in the version 3.0, when I try to position the 3D cursor with SHIFT + RIGHT CLICK it's in the wrong place. As you know when using this method the cursor should be positioned on the surface of the object, but in my case it is inside the object and I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the select tool (the default tool), the 3D cursor should always snap to the surface that you clicked.

If it doesn't work for whatever reason, you can use the 3D cursor tool and make sure that `Surface Project` is checked :

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes it is enabled

Comment: So, did it solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable 'Cursor Surface Project' in Preferences > Editing > 3D Cursor

[image]

This affects the positioning with `Shift` + `RMB` even if the cursor is not the active tool.
It´s similar to 'Surface Project' when cursor is active and placed with left click.